# can go to HTML <section> Tag in code behind?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a page with malty `Section` tag. That the  homepage section is main section, when i click every link, go to special section.

```
<section id="homepage" class="page-homepage current-page page">
    <a class="nav-link" data-opening-page-id="tariff-page" href="#tariff"></a>
    <a class="nav-link" data-opening-page-id="agancy-page" href="#agancy"></a>
</section>
<section id="agancy-page" class="page Gold-page">
    <div class="hide-show back-button-holder">
        <div class="outer-circle pull-left">
            <asp:Button ID="AgancySendButton" runat="server" Text="Send" Width="150px" OnClick="AgancyFile" ValidationGroup="agancy" OnClientClick="return ValidatePage('agancy')" CssClass="btn-submit" />                                                
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="complate-page" class="page Gold-page">
    <div class="hide-show back-button-holder">
        <div class="outer-circle pull-left">
            <div class="inner-circle">
                <a class="nav-link" data-opening-page-id="homepage" href="#homepage"></a>
                <i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-title">
            <h2><i style="font-size: 25px" class="icon-tick-outline"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ثبت اطلاعات</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    </div>
</section>
```

When i click on Button and run click event, back to homepage section, I want to go complate-page section when run button click.

Can go to special section in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

you can use panel that use ajax, also you can use find control in code behind, after that
do something (if you want to add some html code dynamic in your page you can use literal.

[sample ajax panel](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but when pase is post back, go to main section. I do't show panel.

Comment: try to use 
`Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
Dim objContentPlaceHolder As New ContentPlaceHolder`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with local-links, like

```
    <a href="#id">Go to ID</a>
```

and then use some jQuery

Comment: Thanks, I send email and sms in button event. I want to go special section after send email,sms.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly then you have a decently big page with a button on top and with a section with an id say "special_sec" somewhere below. On click of the button you need to execute some server code and then bring that "special_sec" into view.

I have tried to simulate what you need.

**aspx page:**
Here I have tried to make the page bigger by adding `br` tags

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Practice_Web.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <!--Tried to increase the page size to simulate a big page -->
        <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <section id="special_sec">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hello</a>
        </section>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**On server side button click:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do some server side stuff here
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "javascript:$(\"#special_sec\").get(0).scrollIntoView();", true);
}
```

You can include this in your code as per your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i use this but when i click button go to homapage section.

Comment: When client clicks on button, do you want to go to homepage section? In that case you can replace "special_sec" in javascript:$(\"#special_sec\")... in my example with id of whatever section you want. You can put the id of your homesection, #homepage in your case.

Comment: No, i want to go special_sec. I use this code, but when i run it. go to homepage rather than special_sec. don't work this script for me.

Comment: Then please elaborate what is special_sec? Is it another section on the same page? Please provide html for the same, it would be better if you update your question.

Comment: My code should work. Add a few br tags in between the sections so that the page becomes long enough i.e. the section "complate-page" should not be visible when the button is visible. Then try. If this is not working then show me your "AgancyFile" method (at least partial) along with my code in it.

Comment: I use `            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "javascript:$(\"#complate-page\").get(0).scrollIntoView();", true);
`,

Comment: Check if your javascript function "ValidatePage" is return true or not. If it is returning false then your server side button click event will not get fired. If it is returning true then keep a breakpoint on the code you mentioned in your comment and check if the breakpoint is hitting.